# How to make a UIButton appear when certain parameters are met objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a button appear once the user has entered over 3 characters in the username and log in field. I set up an if statement, but I just do not know how to create the button programmatically...Any ideas?

Comment: I created a button on storyboard...dont know if that helps

Comment: Add from xib, make it `hidden` show it when needed?

Comment: There are lot of links available for how to create button programmatically u can check those links

Comment: If you already have a button on storyboard, connect IBOutlet and use  UIButton's setHidden: method.

Comment: @iphonic if i were to make it hidden how would i go about showing it when it is needeD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a button programmatically would look something like this:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width/3, self.view.frame.size.height/8)];
button.titleLabel = @"My Button!"
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: I prefer the `buttonWithType` method. And where to the strange factors come from?